# Can not configure AWS SES to send email from Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-ses

I have created an SES Account and I have verified my domain in Mumbai region.

Now in Cognito on managing user pools on tab "**Message customizations**" I'm trying to configure Cognito+SES. But on field "**SES Region**" there is no Mumbai region (only Virginia, Oregon, Ireland). Therefore I can't choose "**FROM email address ARN**".

What I'm doing wrong? Or what I'm missing?

Answer (score 6):

Create SES account in the same region as it is showing on cognito SES region i.e.(only Virginia, Oregon, Ireland).
After creating the account, when you refresh the page, now you can see the email address created by you in the cognito SES region dropdown list

Comment: thanks...I was looking for the solution for the last 1.5 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Switching to new Cognito console solved this for me.

In the old console I had only 3 regions available and many tricky things to be done before setting FROM field - like creating new Cognito user pool in available regions.

After switching to new console I just entered an email address from verified domain.

Comment: This worked for me too. Thanks for the solution. I was trying to fix this for a couple of days and it was a simple solution to switch to the new console.